# Seeing error when trying to write the data from Dataframe to Excel sheet - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

While trying to write the data from Pandas Dataframe to Excel sheet, I am seeing error as " from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'"

Even though I have imported the openpyexcel package, below is my code. Please help me

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
from openpyexcel import workbook

tree = et.parse("Test_Cust.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
print(root)

myrows = []

for items in root.iter():
    if items.tag == "Email":
        cust_email = items.text
    elif items.tag == "CompanyName":
        cust_company = items.text
    elif items.tag == "FirstName":
        cust_firstname = items.text
        myrows.append({"Email":cust_email, "Company Name":cust_company, "FirstName":cust_firstname})

out_df = pd.DataFrame(myrows)
out_df.to_excel("MySheet.xlsx" , index=False)
print("Done")
```

Comment: You need to install the `openpyxl` package. `pip install openpyxl` or whatever package manager you use. Also, no need to import after you install. pandas will use in the background

Comment: @ArthurBorshenko, I have already installed openpyexcel, but still seeing this error, installed the same from command prompt and from venv too

Comment: In your code you have openpyexcel, shouldn't it be openpyxl?

Comment: @norie, thanks for your help, actually I am running test automation framework - selenium webdriver, and there is one similar package named "openpyexcel", hence bit oversight.. Thanks for the sparkling answer(suggestion). Good day

Comment: As fas as I'm aware pandas doesn't support openpyexcel.https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html